# Django Proxy model returning parent model

Tags: python, django, proxy

I am having a strange issue here with django 1.6.5.

### In distribution.models I have:

```
from core.models import Book, Person

class Proxy1(Book):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

class Proxy2(Person):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

### how can this happen?:

```
>>> from distribution.models import Proxy1, Proxy2
>>> type(Proxy1.objects.first())
<class 'core.models.Book'>
>>> type(Proxy2.objects.first())
<class 'distribution.models.Proxy2'>
```

Any ideas where to hunt for the cause?

Comment: Is it the same type on all the Proxy1 and Proxy2 objects? (not the `first`only)?

Comment: Uhh, have you try restarting the shell?

Comment: I'd be curious to know how your objects are instantiated.

Comment: @AamirAdnan Yes just tried with a fresh shell... doesn´t help...

Comment: @DavidW. all models use their standard `__init__`

Comment: Maybe (or maybe not) pasting Book and Person models could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of hours hunting I finally found the culprit. The MoneyField from the django-money package does some dark magic on the model manager that somehow breaks returning the correct model class for proxy models. I filed an issue: https://github.com/jakewins/django-money/issues/80

I settled with an easy workaround by manually overriding the 'objects' attribute on the proxy class like this:

```
class ProxyModel(SomeModelWithMoneyField):

    # This fixes django-money that would else return parent objects
    objects = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        proxy=True
```

Comment: The same issue in django-filer. Titusz thx for this question/answer you save my time ;)